# Scorm player for offline content view on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, scorm

I have search lot for the scorm player so, that i can run scorm file locally on iPad.
But i am failed to find.
Can anybody know how to implement scorm player?
Any link or piece of code appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you find anything please share with me. I am also search it from last 15 days.

Comment: @HiddenDeveloper, can you write answer as you are familiar with scorm for iPad, i don't want to waste my bounty to a person who does not know what is scorm?

Comment: Did you get the solutions ?

Comment: @Mangesh Vyas, I have leave that till scorm will implement solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention your [link](http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-untethered). Just contact them and also update me on this question.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a driver already written : http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-driver/scorm-driver-technical-details/

However, it's not native, it's javascript.

What's stopping you put it inside a `UIWebView`?

Comment: have you integrate that in any of you application? http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-untethered/ ,they had clearly written that it is not yet implement, they are working on it. i have also mail then for this and they replied me they are still working for iOS and Android...

Comment: @iPhoneiPadDev, they have not implemented, they will be your partner to help you to implement. Just contact them to become your partner and they will guide you.

Comment: @deanWombourne, if you don't have implemented then why are you replying like this. Get detail of question and then reply.

Comment: @HiddenDeveloper, i have contacted them, they told me that they are working on it and they will let me know when it will be ready.

Comment: @HiddenDeveloper Because the question was asked on Mar 9th and no=one had answered - the link might have been a point in the right direction. As it happens, my answer caused you to comment (and answer) which helped the OP. Sometimes, old questions just need a poke to get people interested in them again :)